# update SpanSizeLookup after item removal in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I am using GridLayoutManager for recyclerview with spansize of 1 and 2

```
GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup spanSizeLookup = new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {

        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                case TYPE_HEADING:
                    return 1;
                default:
                    return 2;
            }
        }
    };
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mContext, arrItems);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The recyclerview shows perfectly. But then if I remove one item from the recyclerview the spansize reverses ie spansize for TYPE_HEADING becomes 2 and 1 otherwise.

Code to remove item.

```
arrItems.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

How to fix this

Comment: Can you show how you remove item from RecyclerView?

Comment: updated code to show how am I removing the item